# I am getting a token error but in the script Token is getting passed and API's are getting failed

Tags: performance, api, jmeter

{"error":"IDX12709: JWT is not well formed: '[PII is hidden]'.\nThe token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'."}
Token is getting passed but when I am executing the api's i am getting the above error

Comment: The above error is from API response data in Jmeter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.